# Reduction of the Helmholtz equation for an electric field with only an $\hat{x}$ component and uniform (no variation) in the $x$ and $y$ directions

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electric-fields, maxwell-equations

I am currently studying the textbook *Microwave Engineering*, fourth edition, by David Pozar. Chapter **1.4 THE WAVE EQUATION AND BASIC PLANE WAVE SOLUTIONS** says the following:

> **The Helmholtz Equation**
>
> In a source-free, linear, isotropic, homogeneous region, Maxwell's curl equations in phasor form are
> $$\nabla \times \bar{E} = -j \omega \mu \bar{H} \tag{1.41a}$$
> $$\nabla \times \bar{H} = j \omega \epsilon \bar{E}, \tag{1.41b}$$
> and constitute two equations for the unknowns, $\bar{E}$ and $\bar{H}$. As such, they can be solved for either $\bar{E}$ or $\bar{H}$. Taking the curl of (1.41a) and using (1.41b) gives
> $$\nabla \times \nabla \times \bar{E} = - j\omega \mu \nabla \times \bar{H} = \omega^2 \mu \epsilon \bar{E},$$
> which is an equation for $\bar{E}$. This result can be simplified through the use of vector identity (B.14), $\nabla \times \nabla \times \bar{A} = \nabla (\nabla \cdot \bar{A}) - \nabla^2 \bar{A}$, which is valid for the rectangular components of an arbitrary vector $\bar{A}$. Then,
> $$\nabla^2 \bar{E} + \omega^2 \mu \epsilon \bar{E} = 0, \tag{1.42}$$
> because $\nabla \cdot \bar{E} = 0$ in a source-free region. Equation (1.42) is the *wave equation*, or *Helmholtz equation*, for $\bar{E}$. An identical equation for $\bar{H}$ can be derived in the same manner:
> $$\nabla^2 \bar{H} + \omega^2 \mu \epsilon \bar{H} = 0. \tag{1.43}$$
> A constant $k = \omega \sqrt{\mu \epsilon}$ is defined and called the *propagation constant* (also known as the *phase constant*, or *wave number*), of the medium; its units are $1/m$.
>
> **Plane Waves in a Lossless Medium**
>
> In a lossless medium, $\epsilon$ and $\mu$ are real numbers, and so $k$ is real. A basic plane wave solution to the above wave equation can be found by considering an electric field with only an $\hat{x}$ component and uniform (no variation) in the $x$ and $y$ directions. Then, $\partial/\partial{x} = \partial/\partial{y} = 0$, and the Helmholtz equation of (1.42) reduces to
> $$\dfrac{\partial^2{E_x}}{\partial{z}^2} + k^2 E_x = 0. \tag{1.44}$$

I'm confused about this part:

> In a lossless medium, $\epsilon$ and $\mu$ are real numbers, and so $k$ is real. A basic plane wave solution to the above wave equation can be found by considering an electric field with only an $\hat{x}$ component and uniform (no variation) in the $x$ and $y$ directions. Then, $\partial/\partial{x} = \partial/\partial{y} = 0$, and the Helmholtz equation of (1.42) reduces to
> $$\dfrac{\partial^2{E_x}}{\partial{z}^2} + k^2 E_x = 0. \tag{1.44}$$

If the electric field only has an $\hat{x}$ component, as stated, then how does it make sense to say that it has "uniform (no variation) in the $x$ and $y$ directions"? Shouldn't there not be anything in the $y$ direction? And how does this all reduce the Helmholtz equation to $\dfrac{\partial^2{E_x}}{\partial{z}^2} + k^2 E_x = 0$? I would appreciate an explanation with mathematics that illustrates this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equation 1.44 is for (an infinite) plane wave propagating in the $z$ direction. The $\mathbf E$ vector points in the $x$ direction and is assumed to have the same value for all values of $x$ and $y$. It does vary with $z$ and $t$.

Comment: Oh, ok, I see what it's saying now.